# I accidentally changed a mount option in Disks and can't boot anymore

Tags: boot, mount, 17.10

I have a SSD I boot from, and a HD for most of my data.

The HD doesn't mount until I click on it in Nautilus. Trying to fix this, I probably changed some setting in Disks for the SSD instead of HD. Probably this:

**Settings > edit mount options > User sessions default: On**

All worked fine after that. But after rebooting, my 17.10 PC is stuck at startup, reaching a first orange screen, but not reaching the login screen. In recovery mode I see:

```
[Errno 30]Read-only file system
```

I would appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Maybe you have broken the configuration of the file /etc/fstab. You will have to fix it from recovery mode or using a live USB.

Comment: I tried that, not working. Probably because this is the SSD for booting. So this disk can't have an entry in fstab as there can't be a mount point at booting time.

Comment: You may need to set the usb as a boot option in the BIOS. Make it the first boot device. This option may not appear if you don't have a drive plugged in.

Comment: @stephen. How would this make my SSD bootable again? :)

Comment: Can someone report the flags or settings in "Disks" being used on their primary drive? Then i can copy them in my "Disks" after booting with usb drive.

Comment: Here is the fstab setting for my boot drive. You can get the UUID of your SSD by using the blkid command run as root or via sudo.

    ''''UUID=286de99c-8d94-4b54-ba3e-916c0b2dbebd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

Comment: To fix the fstab: open a terminal (CtlAlt t). Then enter sudo nano /etc/fstab. I don't use the Disks application  so can't help you there but perhaps the fstab entry I posted above will help you out, however the Disks application no doubt sets the fstab values.

Answer (score 0):

I backed up , fully erased and reinstalled my SSD and all was working. Then as a test I replicated the problem by changing the settings in Disks. So be careful in that application. Then again reinstalled and all well now.

Comment: Congratulations on figuring out the problem! Perhaps someday users will be certified before making system administration changes to thier system.

Comment: Regarding your question *But after plenty of online searches I still wonder what makes a disk bootable.* open source developer [Rod Smith](https://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith) is Ask Ubuntu's expert on that subject. I agree with you that studying one facet of Ubuntu well is a good thing, at least it works for me. I help other users to improve their answers about my favorite topic and they help me to improve my answers about their favorite topics, but if I don't have enough time I stop posting about everything except for my favorite domain.

Comment: @Johan Sorry to have given you so much frustration. Contrary to your experience I find many helpful suggestions on this site . I confess that I did not fully grasp your situation.Would this have helped? There is a reference to Boot Repair. Google 'ubuntu make disk bootable'

Comment: For those wondering what the last 3 users are replying to, my previous answer was 80% trimmed of all non-tech info by editor Thomas Ward.  No problem, I respect this site's way of working. @Stephen, Thanks for the extra info !

Answer (score 0):

I just made the same mistake. You don't necessary have to reinstall your system. The problem is that you remove the line of you drive in `/etc/fstab`. You just have to manually recreate this line.

0. Backup you current file `/etc/fstab` (one mistake is enough!):

   `cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab-backup`
1. Start Ubuntu in recovery mode and choose root terminal.
2. Find the disk you remove and get its UUID with the following command:

   `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`
3. Remount you disk, otherwise the file `/etc/fstab` is read only (replace `/dev/sda2` by the appropriate path):

   `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2`
4. Edit the file `etc/fstab`:

   `nano /etc/fstab`

Add this line at the end of the file (replace the disk UUID by the one you get at step 2.) :

```
`UUID=d1d5cbab-5ed4-4e8f-910c-12f5710c10a1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`
```

**Tip:** to avoid mistake with your disk UUID, you can append the output of the disk list directly in `/etc/fstab`. Then remove everything except your UUID.

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ >> /etc/fstab`